# "All this time" or "All these time"?

Tags: time

Is "time" plural in the expressions "all the time" and "all these time"? Which is correct?

The first result I get on [Google](https://ask.fm/The_YUNiversity/answers/135554524034) states that the latter is not idiomatic, but apparently "all these moments" are better... I would like to stick to the word 'time', however.

Context:

`Even after all this time, he could still remember...`

Comment: Did you post the right link? It says '"All these times" is not idiomatic.', which is **not** saying that it's correct.

Comment: "All these time" is not correct, and the linked answer does not say it is. Read more carefully.

Comment: Sorry, it appears that I did not read the link fully. So it was not necessarily correct.

Comment: There's also the question of if there are discrete moments in time (as in your link).  For example if someone was late six times in the past week and when asked gave an excuse you might say "Do you remember all these times you were late?"  This is different than the example in the link "Do you remember all these times?"  which feels odd to my ear without context/an antecedent for "these times" .  If you have the context I would say 'time' is not plural and you should use 'these times'.

Comment: Interestingly, this question appears to hark more deeply at the methods by which English speakers count, such as less vs fewer.

"Fewer" is appropriate where the referenced quantity is an integer.
"Less" when not definitively an integer.

"Fewer than six people"
"Less than six percent of people"

And even more vague logic applies when referencing Time.

Time itself is immutable, so cannot be plural.  However instances in time are, by definition, plural, so are rightly referred to as times.

Comment: I have added the context, please let me know if I should include the entire passage instead.

Comment: _Time_ is not plural. Ever. The plural is _times_, with an s. _These_ is only used with a plural, so _these time_ is never grammatical. Of course, _time_ can be a non-count noun, but that doesn't change its grammatical number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Time' in the abstract sense is uncountable, as in 'all the time' or 'after all this time'. However, as Dan says, 'a time' can also mean an occasion when something happened, as in 'you were late six times'. So you could say 'Even after all these times you have been unkind to me, I still love you'.